# Roots of a Monic polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

[image]
My attempt
Product of roots=(-1)^n sincep(-1)=0 and given no roots inside the unit disc.Hence no roots outside the unit disc.
Then all the roots are on the unit circle.
Hence p(2)>0 true, p(3)=0 false.
Is p(1)=0

Comment: Seems fine to me.

Comment: I don't know to prove or disprove p(1)=0.Can u plz direct me.Why is it necessary that 1 is a root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $\;p(0)=-1$ and $\,\lim_{x \to \infty}p(x) = + \infty\,$ on the real axis, so if $p(1) \ne 0$ there would exist at least one real root either inside $(0,1)$ or in $(1, \infty)$. In the latter case, consider that `all the roots are on the unit circle` means that $x^n\,p(1/x)$ has all roots on the unit circle as well.

Comment: Ur answer seems perfect..Thanku